# Performance impact of using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm thinking to use Swashbuckle for WebAPI Swagger documentation.

Was wondering if there is any performance impact to take into consideration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slight overhead during app startup but the thing you really need to look out for is that the HTTP call to request the UI/docs is an expensive and potentially long-running one. You therefore want to make sure you are caching your documentation. This is now possible by overriding the default swagger provider in your SwaggerConfig.cs Register method:

```
c.CustomProvider(defaultProvider => new CachingSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider));
```

And then implementing the `ISwaggerProvider` interface in your `CachingSwaggerProvider` class. See an example class [in the GitHub documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/App_Start/CachingSwaggerProvider.cs)